# Phonegap: key required for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, blackberry

I have started trying Phonegap. While it gives the .apk and .xap, but not for iOS and blackberry and asks for a key.

Can someone provide useful links for developing in iOS and understanding what are the keys mentioned?

Comment: Can you add more information to your question, please? Are you using `build.phonegap.com` or the command line interface? What is the exact error message you are getting? What have you tried already? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am using Phonegap build.

Comment: It says,
"No key selected. You must provide a signing key, first"

Comment: As described below, you need to get an Apple iOS developer account. From there you will be able to create a certificate and provisioning profile that you will have to upload to PGBuild in order for your iOS app to build properly. Get the account first, then google "create p12 file from provisioning profile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to develop for iOS, you need an Apple Developer Account. This is costs $99/year, and you can find out the specifics here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

I've never gone through the process myself, but as I understand it, once you sign up to be an Apple developer, they'll give you a key (or some way of generating one) that every program that can build apps for iOS will require before it can build successfully. There is no way to develop for iOS without first subscribing to the developer program.